# Engine Unity5 erro no código

Tags: c#, unity3d, unity-5

Eu estava criando um código para o um jogo e no final apareceu alguns problemas:

```
Assets/Scripts/Player/PlayerMovement.cs(63,23): error CS1547: Keyword `void' cannot be used in this context

Assets/Scripts/Player/PlayerMovement.cs(63,26): error CS1525: Unexpected symbol `(', expecting `)', `,', `;', `[', or `='
```

O código está assim:

```
void Turning ()
{
    Ray camRay = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);

        RaycastHit floorHit;

        if(Physics.Raycast(camRay, out floorHit,camRayLenght, floorMask) )

        {
            Vector3 playerToMouse = floorHit - transform.position;
            playerToMouse.y = of;

            Quaternion newRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(playerToMouse);
            playerRigidbody.MoveRotation(newRotation);
        }
         void Animating  (float h, float v);

        }
```

[image: Evidência]

Comment: Leandro, bem vindo ao SOPT. Este site não é um fórum. Se não fez ainda, faça o [tour] por favor. Se alguma resposta resolveu o seu problema, considere aceitá-la (marcando-a ao clicar no "v" abaixo da pontuação). Lembre-se também de abrir outra pergunta para uma nova dúvida/dificuldade. :)

Comment: entendi obrigado , mais ainda nao resolveu totalmente o meu problema

Comment: Resolveu os erros desta pergunta, não resolveu? Como eu disse, esse site **não é** um fórum. Se vc tem outra dúvida, abra outra pergunta. Se quer ajuda passo-a-passo, sugiro procurar alguém com interesse em te ajudar no [chat] (mas honestamente eu não sei se vc já tem reputação suficiente pra participar do chat - teste pra ver, ok?) ou em outro site. Boa sorte! :)

Comment: obrigado Luiz Vieira

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Erro está na função

```
void Animating  (float h, float v);
```

Onde o correto seria você definir ela fora de `void Turning ()`

Comment: vou tentar arrumar .Agora apareceu outro erro

Comment: @LeandroYoshida Deu certo?

Comment: Uma parte sim , mas apareceu outro erro , no Animating

Comment: @LeandroYoshida Pode fazer outra pergunta que ajudarei a resolver.

Comment: Quero mandar mais um print para mostrar melhor o problema

Answer (score 3):

Estás a tentar definir, mal, a função Animating. Primeiro porque ainda não fechaste a anterior (Turning) e depois porque tens que abrir um bloco a seguir aos parametros. Fica assim:

```
void Turning () { 
  Ray camRay = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
  RaycastHit floorHit;
  if(Physics.Raycast(camRay, out floorHit,camRayLenght, floorMask) )
  {
    Vector3 playerToMouse = floorHit - transform.position;
    playerToMouse.y = of;
    Quaternion newRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(playerToMouse);
    playerRigidbody.MoveRotation(newRotation);
  }
}

void Animating  (float h, float v){
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Leandro,

Percebi que você colocou a letra O ou invés do numero 0 em algumas linhas, como por exemplo está:

```
playerToMouse.y = of;
```

Claro, a menos que você tenha uma variável com o nome of