# Erro No Código Unity5

Tags: c, unity-5

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Estou com dois erros , não estou conseguindo arrumar

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Olá novamente, Leandro. Vou te dar algumas dicas pra você conseguir ajuda mais facilmente no futuro, e também pra você melhorar suas habilidades de programação. O primeiro erro é exatamente o mesmo [da sua outra pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/129387/73). Lá tem duas respostas, você aceitou uma (provavelmente da pessoa que mais te ajudou em comentários), mas a outra resposta está mais completa. Se tivesse analisado ela, veria que o corpo do método precisa ser completamente declarado. A resposta está lá, *vc só não prestou atenção*.

Comment: Eu só não votei pra fechar esta pergunta como duplicada porque ela também outro erro/problema a seguir. Esse segundo erro provavelmente também é falta de atenção (talvez vc esteja seguindo um tutorial?). Além disso, vc vai notar que esta sua pergunta recebeu votos negativos. A razão é porque ela está mal feita. No futuro, procure colocar os trechos de código e o texto do erro ao invés de imagens de tela nesses casos. E, mais uma dica pro futuro: leia as mensagens de erro. Sei que estão em inglês (use o tradutor do Google!), mas elas existem justamente pra explicar o porquê do erro. :) []s

Comment: Obrigado Luiz . Melhorarei

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Método  `void Animating  (float h, float v)` deve ser declarado assim

```
void Animating  (float h, float v){

}
```

O segundo erro é pelo fato de provavelmente floorHit não ser um `Vector3`.

Se você quiser diminuir alguma possição do transform e atribuir na variável `playerToMouse` , terá que usar dessa forma:

`Vector3 playerToMouse = 
new Vector3(transform.position.x, transform.position.y,transform.position.z);` e diminuir da possição que você quer pelo floorHit.

Comment: obrigado pela ajuda